# Will upgrading to Windows 10 mess up my SSD+HDD setup?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, windows-10

So after about an hour of registry editing and Users folder moving, I finally set up my SSD and HDD system. I bought Windows 7 Home Premium, not knowing that it only supports 16GB of RAM when I have 24GB, and I know Windows 10 Home supports way more, or at least 24GB, so I was thinking about upgrading. The only problem is, will anything I have done be messed up in the process of upgrading? I moved the Users folder with all the correct permissions from the C: (SSD) drive to my D: (data, HDD) drive, then created a symlink from C: to D:, so Windows looks at the hard drive when booting my desktop. I also editing the registry so that the default installation path in the registry so that everything is installed in my hard drive.

So I'm wondering, will everything boot as it is now if I upgrade to Windows 10?

Comment: Before I do any major changes on my computer, first I test it on virtual box. It is free and it can save You a lot of trouble. If I were You, the first thing I would try is to export my registry settings, install Win 10 on virtual box, and apply the exported registry settings there to see if it is stable.

Comment: Could I do the "Go back to Windows 7" option in Win10 if it did mess it up? I also have space to back my current install up.

Comment: Yes, it is possible if You follow these steps: http://www.howtogeek.com/220723/how-to-uninstall-windows-10-and-downgrade-to-windows-7-or-8.1/ - I did not try this yet so - You should also go for sure and create a *shadow copy* to ensure your settings will get saved and You can restore them. But I still find Virtual Box the best possible solution

Comment: Does Virtual Box access my two drives and everything?

Comment: No, You create a virtual drive and you can create the same circumstances as if You had 2 drives. Great for test purposes. It is easy to use. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dbblu_HVROk

Comment: ugh. Chances here are no, and backing this up might be tricky. *Backup*.